# Django-How to activate new env

Tags: django, virtualenv

i have an issue with activating my virtual env. I added the django library but cannot activate my django library. What should i do next ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9hCu.png

Answer (score 0):

- to create an environment (venv its environment name)

```
virtualenv venv
```

- for activate environment

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Learn how to use google, it will be very useful

Comment: I know how to use google, the source is the path of the file or something ?

Comment: When you create a virtual environment, you create a folder (for example "venv") and it has a folder "bin", inside the "bin" there is a file "activate"
Here I am talking about "virtualenv", if you have another package installed, then the activation of the environment may differ, then you should read the documentation

Answer (score 0):

it's better to use something like [`poetry`](https://python-poetry.org/)

```bash
poetry add django
poetry shell
```